# Company refuses to pay and does not have an address

Tags: freelancing, salary

I worked for a particular start up sometime ago, but got a bad check in the mail after the work. Since it was a start-up, I decided to give some time before I demand my money. Problem is the company does not have a valid address and my lawyer says that is needed if he is to deliver the papers.

I know this company is still in business as the website is still up. How do I go about getting my money? Also, what rights do I have as an ex-employer to wages unpaid, in general?

Comment: Did they sign any sort of contract or documentation, or did they just tell you face to face that they would pay you?

Comment: It is a crime to pass a bad check.  Consider contacting your state attorney general's office.

Comment: I signed contracts in both cases. I am wondering if I can just walk into the local police station for the one.

Comment: `Problem is the company does not have a valid address` -- Good luck getting paid then.  They're probably defunct.  If the amount is small enough, you can try suing them in small claims court; you need a judgement before law enforcement can act, and they can't act without a valid address or person to go after.  I agree with Kevin: contact your AG.

Comment: Do you have an image of the check they gave you?  Is the address on it invalid?

Comment: Maybe you can find their address by doing a `whois` on their domain name?

Comment: The whois information contains the address that the lawyer says is not the correct address.

Comment: @RacMain: Whose address is it? Maybe you can take action to have them suspend the domain until the cheque is cleared? Is there anything your lawyer can do with the whois info?

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is a bit dependent on your jurisdiction, I think.  How and if businesses have to register with the government, and what to do if they have not, will vary by state.  I know a little about how it works in Minnesota and Iowa in the U.S., but I have no idea where you are.

Comment: I am in Illinois. I am not sure whose address is on the Whois information really. I did give the lawyer the check copy I got from the bank, and that is all I have, along with a copy of the NDA I signed with the company. The Whois is registed till 2014 and it was last updated 12th of February this year.

Comment: I'd suggest following the whois info deeper, since it seems to be the only thing you've got.

Comment: I already contacted my lawyer with that information if it will help us.

Comment: Keep nagging them, at least make noise at them to let them know. call, write, email

Comment: @RacMain : Are you sure the company is still in business? I know many websites which last years once the company is defunct. One of my e-mail address is on a server which was announced to be brought down 20 months ago, and I'm still using it.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner : Depending, on the op's country, this can be really a bad idea *(I recognize I only know for EU, but I don't know for US)*.

Answer (score 6):

Since they still have a website up, you can try to lookup an address for them through their domain registry. For example, this [whois query](https://manage.name.com/whois_result?type=domain&domain_name=stackexchange.com&submit=Whois+Search) gives contact info, including street addresses for stackexchange. (Note, that query is through their registrar, which I found through a less informative [query](http://www.networksolutions.com/whois-search/stackexchange.com).)

Also, you might try tracking down addresses of individual people associated with the company.

Talk to your lawyer and see what he can use.

Comment: In some countries, doing this for something involving lawsuits without an approval *([CNIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNIL) in my country)* is illegal. There's also a recent known case *(still in my country)* of a [famous person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omar_Sy) which fell a lawsuit after he got [without approval the location of an individual from his IP address](http://www.arashderambarsh.com/2011/08/internet-que-faire-en-cas-dusurpation.html).

Answer (score 4):

In Illinois, the "official" way to find the "official" address of a business appears to depend how the business was organized.  That is, the business could just be someone operating under an assumed name, or it could be a corporation, or it could be a limited liability company, etc.

For an assumed name, the name and address must be registered with the county.  See [(805 ILCS 405/) Assumed Business Name Act](http://www.ilga.gov/legislation/ilcs/ilcs3.asp?ActID=2299&ChapterID=65).

A corporation must have a registered office in the state.  See [(805 ILCS 5/) Business Corporation Act of 1983](http://www.ilga.gov/legislation/ilcs/ilcs4.asp?DocName=080500050HArt%2E+5&ActID=2273&ChapterID=65&SeqStart=5400000&SeqEnd=6100000).

The laws pertaining to other business organizations appear similar, and it looks like you can find a whole list of them in the [Illinois Compiled Statutes](http://www.ilga.gov./legislation/ilcs/ilcs2.asp?ChapterID=65).  The link lists the laws pertaining to the various business organizations in about as clean a format as I have seen.

Now, it appears that the Illinois Secretary of State [has a page](http://www.cyberdriveillinois.com/departments/business_services/corp.html) allowing you to search for information about a corporation or LLC.  However, since assumed names are just registered with the county in Illinois, you would have to find the county administration offices to get that information.

Finally, if the business is in violation of the registered address laws, you may have to discuss with a (perhaps different) lawyer how to serve them.  In Minnesota, it is permissible to serve process on the Secretary of State for certain similar circumstances, but I do not know whether such a mechanism exists in Illinois.

Comment: Thanks. That website  definitely gave me some assurance that my cause is not lost. I was thinking for a minute there that the story of the company being a registered corporation may have been made up.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the cheque, go in to the cheque-issuing bank (particularly when you'd expect them to have money in their account) and ask the teller to see if the cheque can be cashed. They *will* tell you. Once it can, cash it and you're paid.  Uncommonly known fact.

Comment: I only have a copy of the check.

Comment: @RacMain what happened to the original check?

Comment: Well, I deposited it, and was never able to get it back even though it bounced. Am I supposed to be able to get it back or something? I have a copy of the check though.

Comment: If the check bounced, it should have been returned to you, stamped "INSUFFICIENT FUNDS".  When it bounced, it became physical evidence of a crime.  Talk to your bank.